# How can I register an ECS Service as a Network Load Balancer target on a non-default port?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, aws-elb

I'm trying to deploy a horizontally scaling application consisting of multiple containers with a single reverse proxy in front to AWS ECS backed by EC2. For certain reasons I cannot use an Application Load Balancer, but want to use a Network Load Balancer that forwards all traffic on ports 80 and 443 to the reverse proxy container. I use AWS CDK to define the setup.

I am running into issues when trying to route traffic on *both* ports to the proxy. No matter what I do, all targets in the created target group point to port 80 on the container. I.e. I get a mapping of **80->80, 443->80** when I would like **80->80, 443->443**.

My CDK code looks like this:

```js
const proxyService = new ecs.Ec2Service(this, 'ProxyService', {
  serviceName: 'proxy',
  cluster,
  taskDefinition: proxyTaskDefinition,
  minHealthyPercent: 0,
  desiredCount: 1,
  securityGroups: [securityGroup],
  cloudMapOptions: {
    name: 'proxy',
    cloudMapNamespace: cluster.defaultCloudMapNamespace
  }
})

const loadbalancer = new lb.NetworkLoadBalancer(this, 'NetworkLoadBalancer', {
  vpc,
  internetFacing: true
})

new cdk.CfnOutput(this, 'LoadBalancerDnsName', {
  value: loadbalancer.loadBalancerDnsName
})

loadbalancer.addListener('HTTPListener', {
  port: 80
})
  .addTargets('HTTPTarget', {
    port: 80,
    targets: [proxyService]
  })

loadbalancer.addListener('HTTPSListener', {
  port: 443,
})
  .addTargets('HTTPSTarget', {
    port: 443,
    // the proxyService seems to always register itself at port 80
    // by calling its attachToNetworkTargetGroup method
    targets: [proxyService]
  })
}
```

The Cloudformation generated for the Target Groups looks like this:

```yaml
NetworkLoadBalancerHTTPListener792E96F1:
  Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
  Properties:
    DefaultActions:
      - TargetGroupArn:
          Ref: NetworkLoadBalancerHTTPListenerHTTPTargetGroupCEAF8C0F
        Type: forward
    LoadBalancerArn:
      Ref: NetworkLoadBalancer8E753273
    Port: 80
    Protocol: TCP
  Metadata:
    aws:cdk:path: SplitClusterStack/NetworkLoadBalancer/HTTPListener/Resource
NetworkLoadBalancerHTTPListenerHTTPTargetGroupCEAF8C0F:
  Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
  Properties:
    Protocol: TCP
    TargetType: ip
    VpcId:
      Ref: VPCB9E5F0B4
  Metadata:
    aws:cdk:path: SplitClusterStack/NetworkLoadBalancer/HTTPListener/HTTPTargetGroup/Resource
NetworkLoadBalancerHTTPSListenerAF8F470A:
  Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
  Properties:
    DefaultActions:
      - TargetGroupArn:
          Ref: NetworkLoadBalancerHTTPSListenerHTTPSTargetGroup4BC6FF0B
        Type: forward
    LoadBalancerArn:
      Ref: NetworkLoadBalancer8E753273
    Port: 443
    Protocol: TCP
  Metadata:
    aws:cdk:path: SplitClusterStack/NetworkLoadBalancer/HTTPSListener/Resource
NetworkLoadBalancerHTTPSListenerHTTPSTargetGroup4BC6FF0B:
  Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
  Properties:
    Protocol: TCP
    TargetType: ip
    VpcId:
      Ref: VPCB9E5F0B4
  Metadata:
    aws:cdk:path: SplitClusterStack/NetworkLoadBalancer/HTTPSListener/HTTPSTargetGroup/Resource
```

After deploying this, I can edit the created target groups in the web console to register a new target pointing to 443 on the same IP and deregister port 80 to get things working.

How can I create a Loadbalancer target that:

1. points to the ECS service
2. uses port 443

I'm happy to construct this myself of even add overrides if it helps me get this solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ECS service exposes a `loadBalancerTarget` method that can be used for this:

```js
    loadbalancer.addListener('HTTPSListener', {
      port: 443,
    })
      .addTargets('HTTPSTarget', {
        port: 443,
        targets: [proxyService.loadBalancerTarget({
          containerPort: 443,
          containerName: 'proxy'
        })]
      })
```